# Google Chrome UI Turned Black Randomly, but the hovering UI is still there and any new windows I open still work

Tags: google-chrome, browser, gui, google-chrome-devtools, private-browsing

I was in middle of watching a movie on Google Chrome in fullscreen, and suddenly my whole screen turned black. This just happened to me yesterday, and I fixed it by resizing my window that time, so this time I did the same, I entered and exited fullscreen, I opened a new window ***(that's how I was able to post here in the first place)*** and tried to open a tab on my old window from there, but the old tab stayed black. All my dozens of tabs are still there, my Chrome still works otherwise, and the hovering labels still show, the only thing is that everything else is just black.

How do I fix this without restarting Google Chrome? I've got lots of work saved in many tabs and I can't afford to lose it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Entering and exiting fullscreen
- Resizing the window
- Opening a new window and trying to enter a tab inside the old window via the tabs dropdown menu

Chrome looks fine in Task Manager too. I don't have any other program open except for Chrome itself. I'll repeat this again, I still have my tabs, and I still need them, so closing Chrome is not an option. The only thing is that I cannot see anything on Google Chrome.

There is one "solution" I thought of, if you can call it that, which needs me to *manually* move every tab (I have hundreds) to another window, whilst one window is completely black save for the hovering labels, which, if even done, can result in completely inaccurate tab ordering (since I can't see how they were arranged in the first place). Based on this so-called "solution", you can see how closing my Chrome window is completely unnecessary, since the functionality is all still there, the one problem–(as I have already said) is that my old windows just won't render properly.

Also, if you haven't seen from my comments here, I have tab history, Local Storage, Session Data, and Cookies, which cannot be salvaged if I restart Chrome since it is all stored in an Incognito window.

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: I asked if you are still intererested because this question was "tagged" "Urgent". If you are still interested, please bear in mind that on this site tags should not be included in question titles, and "urgent" is not an appropiate tag for this site. Please [edit] the question to add your progress about what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your session so that if you close or restart the browser the session can be restored.

This can be done using the Chrome extension [Session Buddy (sessionbuddy.com)](https://sessionbuddy.com/).  I  have used it myself for a long time and it has been solid.  Note, I have no affiliation with the developer.

**[Session Buddy](https://sessionbuddy.com/)**
Manage Browser Tabs and Bookmarks with Ease.  The extensions can be installed free from the [Chrome webstore (chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko)

[image]

Comment: There is a setting within Chrome (and most other browsers) to restore open tabs when starting the app, no extensions required.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Incognito mode. I have weeks worth of cookies, localstorage, and sessionstorage, including a Quora, Pinterest, iFunny, Reddit, and Twitter account which all use the same temporary email generated inside this incognito tab. It is imperative I do not restart my Chrome session or else all that data is lost. I am skeptical of the extension you mentioned; does reopen my incognito session after being closed, like it never was closed at all? The idea here is just to somehow refresh Chrome's GUI without resetting anything else. The problem is I don't know how.

Comment: I can slowly move my tabs from one window to another one by one, and it is a valid solution, but it would take far too long. I also have another tab open, that isn't an incognito window, which has hundreds of tabs open each with its own history,  as with my dozens of incognito tabs. Is SessionBuddy open source? The first comment on your answer mentions that SessionBuddy does essentially what Chrome already does, and in that case there is no point in installing the extension, since I also have an Incognito Window to save.

Comment: It doesn't do the same thing as the default settings.  It alliws you to save multiple sessions indnividually and permanently, provide custom names for the saved sessions, and restore them out of order, in the future.